# str_replace with limit argument

Tags: php, arrays, replace, limit

Oh boy this is a doozy. Well I have an array of images in an array with key value.

```
$smiles = array( ':)' => 'http://www.example.com/happy.png', ':(' => 'http://www.example.com/sad.png' );
```

and then I have a text input: `that's sad to hear :(, but also great that you go a new dog :)`

I'm can parse the whole array and replace using the str_replace, but I want a limit of 4 smilies per message.

my old one (no limit):

```
function addSmilies($text){
    global $smilies;

    foreach($smilies as $key => $val)
    {
        $search[] = $key;
        $replace[] = '<img src="' . $val . '" alt="' . $key . '" />';
    }

    $text = str_replace( $search, $replace, $text );
    return $text;
}
```

I understand you can use preg_replace, and that has a limit but I'm horrid with regex and can't get them to do what I want. So back to my question. Is there a str_replace with a limit that works with arrays or should I stick to preg_replace?

UPDATE: I thought about stripping the :) and :( first before I replace with actual  markup.

```
function addSmilies($text){
    global $smilies;

    foreach($smilies as $key => $val)
    {
        $search[] = $key;
        $replace[] = '<img src="' . $val . '" alt="' . $key . '" />';
    }

    $limit = 4;
    $n = 1;

    for($i=0; $i<count($search); $i++)
    {
        if($n >= $limit)
            break;

        if(strpos($text, $search[$i]) === false)
            continue;

        $tis = substr_count( $text , $search[$i] ); //times in string
        $isOver = ( $n + $tis > $limit) ? true : false;
        $count = $isOver ? ($limit - $n) : $tis;

        $f = 0;
        while (($offset = strpos($text, $search[$i])) !== false)
        {
            if($f > $count)
                $text = substr_replace($text, "", $offset, strlen($search[$i]));
            $f++;
        }

        $n += $tis;
    }

    $text = str_replace( $search, $replace, $text );

    return $text;
}
```

but now no images will show at all!?

Comment: `str_replace()` has a fourth parameter called `&$count`. Is anything preventing you using this parameter? Ref.: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: @Bjoern was that just introduced?

Comment: The `$count` parameter returns the number of times that the string was replaced, it is not a limit that you can set.

Comment: Sry, my mistake... to few coffee too properly read the manual. It only returns the number of replacements performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly cleaner function using [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), which contains a limit parameter (you have to add 1 because of the nature of subsets). Basically you split on the string using a regular expression, determine what pattern caused the string to split, and then replace the first four patterns while concatenating the string back together. It results in a cleaner function.

```
function addSmilies($text){
    $smilies = array( ':)' => 'http://www.site.com/happy.png', ':(' => 'http://www.site.com/sad.png' );

    foreach($smilies as $key => $val)
    {
        $search[] = $key;
        $replace[] = '<img src="' . $val . '" alt="' . $key . '" />';
    }

    $limit = 4; //Number of keys to replace
    $return = preg_split('/(\:\)|\:\()/',$text,$limit+1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

    //Concat string back together
    $newstring = "";
    foreach($return as $piece) {
        //Add more if statements if you need more keys
        if(strcmp($piece,$search[0])==0) {
            $piece = $replace[0];
        }
        if(strcmp($piece,$search[1])==0) {
            $piece = $replace[1];
        }
        $newstring = $newstring . $piece;
    }
    return $newstring;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I suppose I coulda messed around with explode, implode, and array_count or something.. this answer is very nice and much cleaner. Thanks!